# OpenJDK11 and eclipse link 2.7.1 Compatibility issue - getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: abcd not found

Tags: java, eclipselink, adoptopenjdk, jpa

Below jars worked fine with OracleJDK 11 but not working with openJDK11.

- eclipselink.2.7.1.jar
- javax.persistence.2.1.1.jar

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: abcd not
> found.    at
> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:362)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1236)
> at
> org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1257)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

Comment: Anything else go wrong with the JVM change? What does logging during persistence unit deployment stay about finding entities and named queries?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.